# codeigniter how to display data base query result as a message in the view and how to redirect same function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

my model looks:

```
public function addMobileAction()
{   
    $mobile = $this->input->POST('mobile',TRUE);

    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM mobile 
            WHERE mobile='.$this->db->escape($mobile);

    $query =$this->db->query($qry);


    $value=$query->num_rows();

    if($value == 0)
    {


        $mobile_id=$this->db->select('mobile_id')->order_by('mobile_id','desc')->limit(1)->get('mobile')->row('mobile_id');
        $mid=$mobile_id+1;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO mobile (mobile,mobile_id) 
                VALUES(".$this->db->escape($mobile).",".$this->db->escape($mid).")";
                $this->db->query($sql);


                return "Registered Sucessfully! Your Id is: ".$mid;

    }

    else
    {
            $mobile_id=$this->db->select('mobile_id')->where('mobile', $mobile)->get('mobile')->row('mobile_id');

            return "Already Registered! Your Id: ".$mobile_id; 

    }
}
```

my controller is

```
public function addMobileProcess()
{ 

    if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'mobile', 'xss_clean|min_length[10]|required');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->home();
        }
        else
        {
            $result= $this->ContentModel->addMobileAction();


                $datasucess['mobileid']=$result;
                $data['sucess'] = $this->load->view('sucess', $datasucess, TRUE);
                $this->load->view('index',$data);     

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

my need is I have to take both **return** values from the **model** and display as a message in **view** based on the condition checked on the model, here the **view** is the same **view** where data get posted.

That means after the data submission I have to redirect to function that call the **view**  and I have to display ***"Already Registered! Your Id: ".$mobile_id;***  if the mobile number is already registered and ***"Registered Sucessfully! Your Id is: ".$mid;*** if the mobile number is new.

How is the redirection to be done? what all modification that I have to done.  I am new to this kind of situation.Thanking all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addMobileAction()
{   
    $mobile = $this->input->POST('mobile',TRUE);

    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM mobile 
            WHERE mobile='.$this->db->escape($mobile);

    $query =$this->db->query($qry);


    $value=$query->num_rows();

    if($value == 0)
    {
        $mobile_id=$this->db->select('mobile_id')->order_by('mobile_id','desc')->limit(1)->get('mobile')->row('mobile_id');
        $mid=$mobile_id+1;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO mobile (mobile,mobile_id) 
                VALUES(".$this->db->escape($mobile).",".$this->db->escape($mid).")";
                $this->db->query($sql);


                return TRUE;

    }

    else
    {
            $mobile_id=$this->db->select('mobile_id')->where('mobile', $mobile)->get('mobile')->row('mobile_id');

            return "Already Registered! Your Id: ".$mobile_id; 

    }
}
```

//Controller

```
public function addMobileProcess()
{ 

    if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'mobile', 'xss_clean|min_length[10]|required');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->home();
        }
        else
        {
            $result= $this->ContentModel->addMobileAction();
//check if result is true or not and perform conditions as per the condition     

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```